# Integrate RBAC in Spring security

Tags: spring-security, user-roles, rbac

I config Spring Security in my web application by this example: http://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration
and this
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression!

I have some questions:

1. What aproach to use: "User > Group > Roles > Permissions" ||  "User > Roles > Permissions"?
2. What is the best practices rules for implements RBAC in Spring Security?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? For question #1 - under what circumstances?